# How to get back to life docker container?

Tags: docker

My docker container hangs and don't have any idea how to get his back to life? I can't stop or restart it, there happens nothing. I can't even export him.

Comment: Is it listed in docker ps?

Comment: If it is showing in `docker ps` you can try to see if the logs for that container show anything interesting: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: It's listed there

Comment: there is nothing interesting in logs :/

Comment: You're going to have to explain exactly what happens and what you expect to happen, with code samples.

Comment: I just entered `docker restart [container id]` and that's it - it hangs :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use service docker restart to restart the docker deamon (assuming you are using linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these ideas :

- Check the problem by looking the logs  **docker logs $container-name**
- You can try to create new image from your container with **docker commit** and create a new container.
- You can create a new container from your initial image or your docker-compose.